# "%s expects argument of type char *, but argument 3 has type char (*)[9]"

Tags: c

So this is the first time I have used scanf() for input, and I have no idea what is causing this error. It seems like the array of characters is not being recognized as the correct data type because it has a max length, but as far as I know there is no other way to declare a string in c... Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "health.h"

Chartptr patientList = NULL;    /* Define global variable patientList (declared in health.h) */
                                /* patientList is globaly accessible in health_util.c    */

void main(){

printf("Welcome to the Health Monitoring System\n\n");

int id, type;
double value;
char time[MAXTIME + 1];
scanf("%d, %s, %d, %lf", &id, &time, &type, &value);
printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("%s: Patient ID = %d checking in", time, id);
addPatient(id);
printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("\nEnd of Input\n");

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change  `&time` to `time` in `scanf` call.

`s` conversion specifier requires a pointer to `char` but you are passing a pointer to an array of `char`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it was so simple :p